# Catchup ou Ketchup?

Tags: estrangeirismos

Qual é o certo?
**Catchup** ou **Ketchup**?

Vejo em embalagens de "molhos de tomates para lanches" escrito catchup e ketchup, e não sei qual o correto.

Answer (score 4):

A definição mais compatível entre variações do português é **ketchup**. No português do Brasil, [existem ocorrências](http://www.dicio.com.br/catchup/) da utilização de **catchup** para o mesmo significado, embora alguns dicionários não a contemplem. As minhas pesquisas levam a crer que esta segunda versão tem raízes desde a exportação para a Europa do antigo molho chinês *kechiap*, ou do molho da Malásia *kicap*, a finais do século XVII [[1](http://mentalfloss.com/article/29649/whats-difference-between-ketchup-and-catsup)], na altura chamando a este molho *catchup*, e *ketchup* pouco tempo depois. Só mais tarde, no século XIX, é que os americanos "reinventaram" o molho com base em tomate, recorrendo não só ao termo *ketchup* como também a *catsup*.

O motivo para a recorrência à palavra catchup por parte dos brasileiros, por esta informação, ainda é um pouco incerto. De todos os modos, é preferível a utilização do estrangeirismo **ketchup**.

Comment: Caso fosse simplesmente uma transliteração do original inglês, não deveria ser algo parecido com "quétchâp"?

Comment: @BrunoLopes Efetivamente, isto deixou-me a pensar. A palavra poderá ter uma outra origem não justificada pelo processo de transliteração. Contudo, não encontro referências fidedignas desta transformação no português do Brasil. Vou adaptar a resposta então.

Comment: O holandês tem [ketjap](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketjap) (um molho de soja holandês) derivada provavelmente do malaio, e também, vindo do inglês através, [ketchup](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketchup). Na Wikipedia, há uma [discussão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketchup#Terminology) sobre a origem da palavra inglesa.

Answer (score 4):

Acrescentando o que o E_net4 disse, a [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) reconhece apenas "ketchup", e é definido como um estrangeirismo vindo do inglês.